# how to assign a div or a table to php

Tags: php, html, css

How can I assign a CSS class or else to an "echo" in order to "style" my external CSS file. My labyrinth game must be centered : text (enigmas) : it's already done, door(s) and link(s). I don't know how to manage that : `echo '<div class... </div>'` ? A table would be the best? I've tried things but nothing happens.

Here's my code :

```
<?php

$piece = 0;
if (isset($_GET["numpiece"]))
{
    $piece = $_GET["numpiece"];
}
echo '<p>' . $indice[$piece] . '</p>';

if ($nord[$piece] != -1)
{
    echo '<a href="index.php?numpiece=', $nord[$piece], '">NORD<img src="door.png" width="50"></a>';
}
?>
```

Comment: I am guessing you would need [a PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) but it is only a guess as your question is not quite clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should code like :

```
<?php
$piece = 0;
if (isset($_GET["numpiece"])) {
    $piece = $_GET["numpiece"];
}
?>
<div id="echo1">
    <?php echo "<p>{$indice[$piece]} </p>"; ?>
</div>
<?php
if ($nord[$piece] != -1) {
    echo "<div id = 'echo2'><a href='index.php?numpiece={$nord[$piece]}'>NORD<img src='door.png' width='50' /></a>";
}
?>
```